# Android Studio 'Device Only' Location w/ Google Play Services not working

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am working on my first app and it is a very simple app. Click button to send Longitude / Latitude to a server/database. I am using Google Play services for location and I am using a Nexus 9 tablet for testing. 
I have found that using Settings>Location (on Nexus 9) - High Accuracy & Low Accuracy works fine. The data is correct and sent to server. But when choosing 'Device Only'(GPS) it does not find the Long/Lat. I get my toast:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I am new to this still so I am not sure where I might have gone wrong. I do have the Manifest file w/

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
```

And Google Play Services in my Gradle file. As it does work w/ WiFi anyways.

Also I did put

```
System.out.println("Longitude (function name)" + longitude + " and Latitude: " + latitude);
```

to view in log when the Long/Lat was being picked up(only when button is clicked, otherwise it's 0.0) In my last test I used High Accuracy and got a Long/Lat. Turned off Wifi and changed locations and it is picking up my new location(but can't send data because no internet connection). So I am confused, as isn't that GPS picking up my new location in High Accuracy?

Not sure if that matters but I would like to have Device Only working for location as well as High Accuracy. 
Any help would be grateful! Here is my code (shortened, if i am missing anything please let me know to add!) Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
    OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private Button btnNewShowLocation;
private double longitude;
private double latitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        //**UPDATED**
        createLocationRequest()
    }
    btnNewShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                postDataToServer("web site address- EDIT");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }}});}
    // **UPDATED** 
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
            .setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL)
            .setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);

private void postDataToServer(String uri) {

    RequestPackage p = new RequestPackage();
    p.setMethod("POST");
    p.setUri(uri);
    p.setParam("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
    p.setParam("latitude", String.valueOf(latitude));
    MyTask task = new MyTask();
    task.execute(p);
    System.out.println("Longitude (post data to server)" + longitude + " and Latitude: " + latitude);

}
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    System.out.println("Longitude (on Connected): " + longitude + " and Latitude: " + latitude);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Searching for your location... \nMake sure WiFi or GPS is turned On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }}}
```

And here is the log notes from High Accuracy on and Wifi turned off.

```
I/System.out﹕ Longitude (on Connected): 0.0 and Latitude: 0.0
I/System.out﹕ Longitude (post data to server)-88.7777777 and Latitude: 55.7777777
W/System.err﹕ java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
```

Wifi is off for that last line.

Comment: I think you need to create the `LocationRequest` object and `setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(interval)
                .setFastestInterval(fastestInterval)
                .setSmallestDisplacement(minDisplacement);` For more details, you can try my code [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/getLastLocationUsingGPS-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bojie/locationex/MapsActivity.java#L87-L93).

Comment: thanks @bjiang I did try that and it did work briefly. Now it is not. I put it in a function 'protected void createLocationRequest() {
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create() .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL)
.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);'                                             And calling it in OnCreate.  In debugger i am getting getLastLocation = null for "device only". I'll keep working on on it

Comment: Have you try my code [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/getLastLocationUsingGPS-android)?

Comment: @bjiang, yeah i did try your code. very nice! thank you! the LocationRequest object did the trick after all. Issue resolved

Comment: Glad to help, cheers! I posted an answer for this, you can accept it if you feel that I helped you~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create the `LocationRequest` object and do as follows:

```
// Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(interval)
                .setFastestInterval(fastestInterval)
                .setSmallestDisplacement(minDisplacement);
```

For more details, you can try my code [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/getLastLocationUsingGPS-android).